# How to make owl sounds

Tags: sound-design, sound, foley, animals

i'm currently working on a mobile game, in wich you have to run a zoo and take care of a dozen of creatures. One of them is an owl. The idea is to make the owl sounds cute and nice not screechy and scary as it sounds in real.

My objective is to make it sound like this :

I've tried several techniques with my own hands, but that doesn't work. So if somebody as an idea to achieve something like in the video, I'd be very happy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sample the reference and pitch it down until it sounds like you could imitate it with your own voice. Record the imitation and pitch it up.

This trick works well for animals with higher voice than your, like birds and rodents.

Comment: Great Idea, I will try it ! Thx